# Distribute elements of column into matrix based on another column

Tags: matlab, matrix

i need help on writing a script that does the following:

```
data = [1 1 2; 
        2 1 3; 
        3 3 4; 
        3 3 5; 
        4 3 6]
```

The script needs to check if a number in the second column is repeated. The sketch below explains what it is I would like to accomplish:

[image]

For each repeated value in the second column, I'd like to all values in the third column that share each repeated value in the second column as entries in the correct column and if the value is not repeated say the 2--->4 as an example, the script will need to check if number 2 belongs to the previous layer if so whatever numbers comes from it will belong to the next layer

### the script provided by Shai solved the above issue

Although, now comes the step of branch numbering, need to number the branches in layers away from the root(node 1) as shown in the pic below. the numbering of branches in one layer starts only after all the branches in the previous layer have been numbered. However, considering the tress structure as a radial electrical distributed generation system, when doing backward sweep iteration(to calculate the current en each node). how can the script tell if for example line7  between nodes 8 and 5 where 5 is also part of line4 etc...? any experts suggestions are welcome
[image]

Comment: I've taken the liberty in rewording your question.  Please let me know if I got the description correct.  I found your first draft to be a bit difficult to understand.

Comment: thanx, my programming lingo is very poor, the wanted result can rather be the way i implemented it (as columns) or (as rows), en both way columns/rows to me they ll be meaning a layer. one more thing the resulting matrix dimensions are not important once the data is classified as asked. hoping i explained it better this time :)

Comment: I get it now. I'd recommend you try a simple loop.

Comment: can you help me with that please?i have tried  loops but i don't seem to figure out the best logic as i was getting errors all the time

Comment: That's a lot different than the first version of this question. That will require a bit of work... Possibly recursion.

Comment: my bad rayryeng as i thought by the solving the first case will be enough, but its actually not ! waiting for any possible solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope I got you right

```
data = [1 1 2; 2 1 3; 3 2 4; 4 3 5; 5 3 6; 6 4 7;7 5 8];
mx=max(data(:,3)); %// maximal node index
```

Estimate the layer of each node (node `1` is in layer `0`):

```
ly = zeros(mx,1); 
for ii=2:mx, 
    ly(ii) = ly( data( data(:,3)==ii, 2 ) )+1; %// get the layer of the parent
end
```

Looking at the layer index of each node (`ly`):

```
0     1     1     2     2     2     3     3
```

Now we split the nodes to columns according to layer

```
for ci=1:max(ly), 
    c{ci} = find(ly==ci); %// put all nodes of layer ci in a cell
end;
```

Number of rows in resulting matrix equals the layer with maximal number of nodes:

```
mxc = max(cellfun(@numel,c));
```

Construct the result

```
res=zeros(mxc,max(ly));
for ci=1:numel(c), 
    res(1:numel(c{ci}),ci)=c{ci}(:);
end;
```

And the result is:

```
res =

 2     4     7
 3     5     8
 0     6     0
```

Comment: Hey Shai !! you have nailed it ! its works fine i tried different example ! thank you very much for your help :)  PS: there is a small mistake on the *construct the result *part res=zeros(mxc,max(pl)); sould be res=zeros(mxc,max(ly));

Comment: i ve added more to it above,now if anyone is interested in solving it :-)

Comment: @gabby113 why don't you ask a new question?

Comment: ah ok didn't know, i thought they 'd close it the thread because it's about the subject , its a good idea im ask a new question thanx

Comment: @gabby113 you can link the new one to this for context