# Distribute elements of column into matrix based on previous column

Tags: forms, matlab, matrix, tree

as a follow to my last [question on layers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34625246/distribute-elements-of-column-into-matrix-based-on-another-column) i need help on writing a script that does the following:

```
data=[1 1 2
      2 1 3
      3 1 4
      4 2 5
      5 3 6
      6 4 7
      7 5 8
      8 5 9
      9 5 10
      10 6 11
      11 7 12
      12 7 13];
```

[image]

numbers the branches according to the requierement on the picture(the original txt) above  considering the tress structure as a radial electrical distributed generation system, when doing backward sweep iteration(to calculate the current en each node). how can the script tell if for example line7 between nodes 8 and 5 where 5 is also part of line4 etc...so basically the result should be matrix which allow sweeping backward in particular order

any suggestions are welcome

Comment: Do you have the Bioinformatics Toolbox?

Comment: The reason that I'm asking is that what you're doing is a Breadth-First Traversal of the tree. The branch number is the discovery order of each node. If you have the Bioinformatics Toolbox, you can use [`graphtraverse`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/graphtraverse.html).

Comment: ahh well i dont think i'am allowed to ,as it has to be written as script, on my last question Shia (a user) helped me sort the nodes by layers and i need to number each line as following the requierement on the pic

Comment: I saw that. The "layer" is the depth of each node. If you're not allowed to use any built-in functions, I would suggest you implement your own Breadth-First Traversal with discovery order and predecessor array. It shouldn't be difficult.

Comment: i ve shortend the question so only the numbering part is considered